# Vgo and private repositories

Tags: git, go, vgo

I am trying to introduce vgo to some of our company projects for dependency management, but I've encountered some issues related to private repository.

Let's assume that we have following code structure:

> go/src/companyName/projectA/
>
> go/src/companyName/projectB/
>
> go/src/companyName/projectC/

All three projects have different git repository and projectA imports projectB.

With normal `go build` approach, as long as we had those directories in place (under git), all worked fine, however we cant't make it work with vgo wrapper.

On `vgo build` following error is being thrown:

> companyName/projectA/ cannot find module providing package companyName/projectB/

Which kind of make sense because with  `vgo get -v` I can see that vgo tries to get meta tags from `https://companyName` which cannot be exposed for company policy.

What's the best way to tell to vgo to either use file system contents (if source files are already there) or to specity git repository for certain import paths?

Comment: Just in case you missed it: vgo [has been merged and will ship with Go 1.11](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-dev/a5PqQuBljF4) in August. You may want to hold off until then, or [experiment with Go tip](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/07/14/taking-go-modules-for-a-spin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this is via the `GOPROXY` environment variable which can be set to a local file.

```
export GOPROXY=file:///path/to/cache
```

for more information, look at; https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/testdata/mod/README